# Can not download file while sending request from one node.js server to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am facing some issue while downloading file using node.js. I have scenario like my angular component is sending the file request. in my first node server I am doing the token validation and then redirecting to another node server where actually the execution happens. I am explaining my code below.

**service.ts:**

```
submitAndDownloadFile(formdata : any ){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + token
    })
    const cecID = localStorage.getItem('cec');
    const AppUrl = `${environment.nodeJsBaseUrl}:${environment.hostingNodeJsContainerPort}/convert-test-cases/${cecID}`;
    return this.httpClient.post(AppUrl, formdata, { responseType: 'blob', observe : 'response', headers : headers});
  }
```

Here I am sending the request to my first node.js server which code has given below.

**app.js(first:port-8000):**

```
router.post('/convert-test-cases/:id',  middleware.auth, (req, res) => {
  try{
            let postRequestOptions = {
                             url: '',
                             method: 'POST',
                             json: true,
                             headers: {},
                             body: {},
             };
            postRequestOptions.url = 'http:localhost:9000/convert-test-cases';
            postRequestOptions.headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            };
            postRequestOptions.body = req.body;
            request(postRequestOptions, async (error, response, pathList) => {
                if(error) {
                    console.log('error', error);
                }else{
                    res.send(pathList);
                }
            })
    
  }catch(e){
    responseObj = {
      status: 'error',
      msg: 'Error occurred while processing your request',
      body: null
    }
    return res.send(responseObj);
  }
})
```

Here I am doing the token validation using `middleware.auth` and sending same request to another node.js file which code is explained below.

**app.js:(second-port-9000):**

```
router.post('/convert-test-cases',  async (req, res) => {
  try{
    let response = await ctcCtrl.convertTestCase(req.body, req.files);
    if(response.status == 'success'){
      res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers','*, Content-Disposition');
      return res.download(response.fileName,response.fileName);
    }else{
      return res.send(response);
    }
  }catch(e){
    responseObj = {
      status: 'error',
      msg: 'Error occurred while processing your request',
      body: null
    }
    return res.send(responseObj);
  }
})
```

Here only I am doing some execution and downloading the file. If I am connecting `angular to node-9000` its working fine but my requirement is first I have to connect to `port-8000` to some token validation and after that I have to send same `req.body and re.file` to `app.js which is running in 9000` using `request` module. As per my code its not working at all.

Comment: why do you use async when there's no await? also you should print out the errors, if it related to validation or the next server request, at least a good question should start with what are the problems rather than said: "As per my code its not working at all." which to ambiguous.

Comment: I wrote async because I have to call some other await method later. Let me to remove it.

Comment: I think what is my requirement, I have explained already.